# How to use 'skip: true' with 'with_first_found'?

Tags: ansible

I would like to use the following task in a playbook:

```
- include: "{{ prerequisites_file }}"
  with_first_found:
    - "prerequisites-{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
    - "prerequisites-{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: prerequisites_file
```

I would like it to just pass if no files matching the architecture were found.

When run as is, in such a case, it produces an error:

> TASK [ansible-playbook : include] ***************************************
>   fatal: [ansible-playbook]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "No file was found when using with_first_found. Use the 'skip: true' option to allow this task to be skipped if no files are found"}

I know I can add a dummy file at the end, but if I were to follow the advice, how am I supposed to add the `skip: true` option here?

<sup>It's definitely not an argument of the `include` module, it should be somehow bound to `with_first_found` clause...</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`with_first_found` has a lot of parameters variations.
Take a look at [first_found.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/first_found.py) – there are some examples in the beginning of the file.

Answering your question:

```
- include: "{{ prerequisites_file }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "prerequisites-{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
        - "prerequisites-{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
      skip: true
  loop_control:
    loop_var: prerequisites_file
```

Comment: Is this `with_first_found` still a thing in Ansible? I can't find a reference to it in the 2.9 documentation (yet it was in the older docs)

Comment: yes, it here - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/first_found.py