# Forced to create file beforehand ansible conditional include

Tags: ansible

```
# "Run application specific configuration scripts"
- include: "app_cfg/{{ app_name }}.yml"
  when: "{{ app_conf[app_name].app_cfg }}"
  ignore_errors: no
  tags:
    - conf
```

I thought that I will be able conditionally include application specific playbooks simply by setting one variable to the `true/false` value like so:

```
app_conf:
  my_app_1:
    app_cfg: no
  my_app_2:
    app_cfg: yes
```

Unfortunately `Ansible` is forcing me to create file beforehand:

```
ERROR: file could not read: <...>/tasks/app_cfg/app_config.yml
```

Is there a way I can avoid creating a bunch of empty files?

```
# ansible --version
ansible 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 2):

`include` with `when` is not conditional in common sense.
It actually includes every task inside include-file and append given `when` statement to every task included task.
So it expects include-file to exist.

You can try to handle this using `with_first_found` and `skip: true`.
Something like this:

```
# warning, code not tested
- include: "app_cfg/{{ app_name }}.yml"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "{{ app_conf[app_name].app_cfg | ternary('app_cfg/'+app_name+'.yml', 'unexisting.file') }}"
      skip: true
  tags: conf
```

It supposed to supply valid config name if `app_cfg` is true and `unexisting.file` (which will be skipped) otherwise.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544405/2795592) answer about skip option.

Comment: Although a little ugly, but still a great feature, which I've totally missed in ansible docs jungle. Thanks!

Comment: I had to un-accept your answer, as it does render an error:
`ERROR: [DEPRECATED]: include + with_items is a removed deprecated feature <...>`

Comment: @NarūnasK consider upgrading to Ansible 2.x: _In 2.0 you are again able to use with_ loops and task includes_.

Comment: I know I should (and eventually I will), unfortunately I don't have this option at present as I then must resolve (potential) mismatch between ansible versions in the great bunch of production playbooks... Thank you for the insights either way.