# ansible ignoring when condition not wrapped in jinja2 format

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

The following task is running regardless of whatever i set as the ansible_distribution.

```
- name: install packages
  yum: name={{item.name}} state=installed
  when: item.when
  with_items:
  - { name: 'telnet', when: "ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'" }
  - { name: 'net-tools', when: "ansible_distribution == 'Debian'" }
  - { name: 'net-tools', when: "ansible_distribution == 'blahblahblah'" }
```

Result

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
 ok: [172.16.2.3]

TASK [test : install packages] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.16.2.3] => (item={u'when': u"ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'", u'name': u'telnet'})
ok: [172.16.2.3] => (item={u'when': u"ansible_distribution == 'Debian'", u'name': u'net-tools'})
ok: [172.16.2.3] => (item={u'when': u"ansible_distribution == 'blahblahblah'", u'name': u'httpd'})
```

Here is my ansible version

```
ansible 2.3.0.0
 config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
 configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
 python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) [GCC 4.8.520150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
```

However when wrap the when condition in jinja2 format like so `"{{item.when}}"`, i get following albeit with a warning.

```
TASK [test : install packages] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{item.when}}

skipping: [172.16.2.3] => (item={u'when': u"ansible_distribution == 'blahblahblah'", u'name': u'httpd'})
skipping: [172.16.2.3] => (item={u'when': u"ansible_distribution == 'Debian'", u'name': u'net-tools'})
ok: [172.16.2.3] => (item={u'when': u"ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'", u'name': u'telnet'})
```

Any idea how i can rewrite this task without having to wrap the when condition in a jinja2 format?

Comment: It's not ignoring, it's dutifully checking the value of the conditional expression and as it is a non-empty string value, it evaluates to `true`. Usually such distinction between architectures is implemented by including different task-files or vars-files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
- name: install packages
  package:
    name: "{{ pkgs[ansible_distribution] | default(pkgs.default) }}"
    state: present
  vars:
    pkgs:
      CentOS: telnet
      Debian: net-tools
      default: net-tools
```

I replaced `yum` module with `package` to make it distro independent, because `yum` will definitely fail on Debian.

I agree with @techraf's comment that if you have a lot of tasks that are different for each distro, consider using `include`/`include_vars` and `with_first_found` to include distro-specific set of tasks/variables (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544405/2795592)).