# How do I make decision based on arch in Ansible playbooks?

Tags: ansible

I have been trying to write playbooks where I can run different tasks based on the arch (i.e amd64, arm, ppc64le) that the playbook is running on. I can not figure out how do I get the arch of the system I am running it on.

How to figure out the arch of the system in Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ansible gathers suitable information from target hosts and stores it as facts, for example: `ansible_architecture`, `ansible_os_family`.

If you are in doubt, you can display all facts with the `debug` module and choose the ones that suit you best.

You can use the `ansible_architecture` facts in `when` conditions, and use it to include different task-files ([an example to customise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39542085/2947502)).

Comment: Thanks, ansible_architecture works well, but there is one issue, for amd64, ansible_architecture shows it as x86_64, to make my playbook work, I need amd64, any idea which fact can give me and64?

Comment: As I mentioned, you only display all facts and check if the one you want is there. If not, you need to implement the check yourself.

Comment: Note that there is also an `ansible_machine` fact, where `ansible_machine` might be `"i686"`, whereas `ansible_architecture` on the same host would be `"i386"`.

Comment: For FreeBSD 13 on POWER, `ansible_architecture` will always return `powerpc` regardless of the actual architecture (powerpc64 or powerpc64le). In part `uname -m` returns the same.

Answer (score 24):

#### To get the architecture of the system

At the command line:

```
ansible HOST -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_architecture'
```

For an x86 architecture host, this would return:

```
HOST | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_architecture": "x86_64"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

Here’s a sample playbook that will print out the architecture of all hosts in your inventory:

```
- name: print out hosts architectures
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
  - debug: var= ansible_architecture
```

#### To run tasks based off the architecture

Use a `when` clause:

```
- name: task to run for x86 architecture
  shell: echo "x86 arch found here"
  when: ansible_architecture == "x86_64"
```

Answer (score 19):

@Pensu it's maybe what you're looking for:

```
- name: Get DEB architecture
  shell: dpkg --print-architecture
  register: deb_architecture

- name: Print DEB architecture
  debug:
    msg: "deb_architecture.stdout: {{ deb_architecture.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

While I was not able to find `ansible_architecture` documented anywhere on [docs.ansible.com](https://docs.ansible.com), here is a list of compiled possible value found while [grepping ansible source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?p=2&q=ansible_architecture):

```
x86_64  # <-- guaranteed to work
aarch64  # <-- found on https://git.e1e0.net/ansible-playbooks/file/roles/node-exporter/vars/main.yml.html
ia64
ppc64le
s390x

# found some matches like:
armv.*
aarch.*
ppc.*
```

Comment: In case it's useful to anyone Raspberry Pi Zero W reports `armv6l`.

Comment: Here is a more complete mapping: `{ "armv6l": "armhf", "armv7l": "armhf", "aarch64": "arm64", "x86_64": "amd64", "i386": "i386" }` (thanks to Cybervitexus - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73096785))