# How is the architecture fact called in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am looking for the fact, which contains the following information:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

I can not find it:

```
$ ansible host -m setup | grep amd64
        "BOOT_IMAGE": "/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64", 
    "ansible_kernel": "4.19.0-6-amd64", 
        "BOOT_IMAGE": "/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do (this works on everything):

```
ansible HOST -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_architecture'
```

Or (this only works on Debian):

```
- name: Get DEB architecture
  shell: dpkg --print-architecture
  register: deb_architecture

- name: Print DEB architecture
  debug:
    msg: "deb_architecture.stdout: {{ deb_architecture.stdout }}"
```

The returned value is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

There might be different systems calling the same architecture using different names because of historical reasons:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#History

Comment: `ansible_architecture` returns `x86_64`. What kind of funny architecture name is this?

Comment: Note that `dpkg --print-architecture` DOES NOT typically print `x86_64`; it prints `amd64`, at least on my machine. Has this changed since 2019? Would be interesting to test this on older Debian/Ubuntu, but I suspect that it's been `amd64` all along.

Answer (score 21):

Using `ansible.builtin.shell` is a bad idea. Because it will change the state everytime. I suggest to use mapping with [ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html).

```yaml
---
vars:
  deb_architecture: {
    "aarch64": "arm64",
    "x86_64": "amd64"
  }
tasks:
- name: Debug message
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ [ansible_architecture] | map('extract', deb_architecture) | first }}"

# like example add docker repo
- name: Add Docker APT repository
  ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
    repo: deb [arch={{ [ansible_architecture] | map('extract', deb_architecture) | first }}] https://download.docker.com/{{ ansible_system | lower }}/{{ ansible_distribution | lower }} {{ ansible_distribution_release }} stable
```

Comment: more complete list ``` 
deb_architecture: {
      "armv6l": "armhf",
      "armv7l": "armhf",
      "aarch64": "arm64",
      "x86_64": "amd64",
      "i386": "i386"
    }     
```

Comment: You can also just use `{{ deb_architecture[ansible_architecture] }}`

Comment: IMHO it's more elegant to suppress task "change" with `changed_when: False` than hardcoded mapping

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for just `amd64` or a few architectures specifically, this should also suffice:

```
{{ 'amd64' if ansible_architecture == 'x86_64' else ansible_architecture }}
```

For example:

```
- name: Set DPKG architecture
  set_fact:
    dpkg_arch: "{{ 'amd64' if ansible_architecture == 'x86_64' else ansible_architecture }}"
```

Credit: https://www.jpdh.ga/tips/ansible.html

Comment: For arm64, it's also wrongly named in ansible, so need to nest another ternary for it: `{{ 'amd64' if ansible_architecture == 'x86_64' else 'arm64' if ansible_architecture == 'aarch64' else ansible_architecture }}`